# Since more than six months

Tags: word-usage

As per English grammar, '*Since*' is used to show the time period in the past from which the event is happening.  So, is the sentence given below correct?

> "*Since more than six months, I have been directly assisting Steve as a Project Manager*"

Comment: @coleopterist,Can you advise how to do it ?

Comment: By accepting suitable answers to your [earlier questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/22492/umesh?tab=questions&sort=newest) just as you have done with this one.

Comment: One other thing: are you implying that you were the project manager, or Steve? The sentence is ambiguous on this!

Comment: @Kris, Nope. Steve is a character in a story in English, I am trying to write :)

Comment: I don't know if you are French but you have used 'since' in exactly the way French uses *depuis*. It is not used like that in English, where one would say *For more than six months, I ....*. You only use 'since' when referring to a point in time e.g. *He has been working on the project since March*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not advisable to use 'since' like you have done, though it may still be correct.

You can use

> I have been assisting Mr. XYZ **for** more than six months.

Or if you want to make a point that you have been assisting someone for a specific period of time, you can use

> I have been assisting Mr. XYZ **since** January.

Assume January is six months before the current month.

Comment: You can use "since" with a point of time expressed as an interval too: "I have been assisting Mr. XYZ since six months ago." But that's a somewhat awkward construction, rarely not equivalent to "for six months". (not equivalent would be "since six months ago, until two months ago, for four months total.")

Answer (score 10):

Your "rule" is wrong. '*Since*' is used to indicate a **point in time past** from which, not a period during which. '*For*' is used to indicate a **period**.

> I've only been married to Sally since July 1st.
>
> It seems as though I've been married to her for æons.

The phrase '*as per*' should be avoided. It strikes people as pompous and stilted. Say instead, "*according to* [the rules of] English grammar."

Don't capitalize '*project manager*' unless it's an official title. (Speakers of British English may think differently about this, though).

Answer (score 5):

Technically, according to your definition, this sentence would be (sort of) correct. However, the usage of the word 'since' in this case feels out of place and really should be written as:

*"For more than six months, I have been directly assisting Steve as a Project Manager."*

Comment: But you didn't say why! I think @Robert Thornton is right on that point.